# How do I call a function after a jquery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, innerhtml

I use jquery load to put a html structure in my body page. Afterwards, I want to call another function to display the table headers. It is suppose to run the function after the load. However, when I insert the completion function in the load parameters, the load is never complete. If I take it out, I don't get to call my function.

**app.js**

```
function insertHTML(){
  var thead = document.getElementByID("thead");
  thead.innerHTML = theadOutput(); //function works fine
}

window.onload = function(){
  $(body).load(body_loc, insertHTML());
}
```

Comment: Adding `()` after function name will call it. remove them to pass reference. Also, since you are already using `jQuery`, use `$(document).ready()` instead of `window.onload`

Comment: Thank You Rajesh. By any chance do you know why () have to be removed? I googled how to do pass reference with arguments in a variable, but I don't understand why Javascript works this way.

Comment: Name is a function is it's reference. When you add () after it, you are calling it and paint is return value. Hence () needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the function reference, instead of calling it:

```
$(body).load(body_loc, insertHTML);
```

Comment: Thank You. I read about pass by ref vs val. I think I understand the big picture. But I don't understand why I had to remove the '()' in terms of the syntax.

Comment: Because when you write `insertHTML()` basically you are calling the `insertHTML` function right away. Whereas when you pass it as reference it is the implementation of the `.load()` method that can decide when exactly to invoke it. In this particular case it will invoke it when the DOM is loaded which is the desired effect. So basically you are passing the load method a delegate that will be invoked at a later time.